# Get exact match of the word using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match exact word from given text using Regex.

Following is the code,

```
var matchterm = "VO";
var pattern = "\\b(" + matchterm + ")\\b";
var text = "FOR OVER FIFTY YEARS WATER FUTURE VOA VO>> VO";
var regx = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var collection = regx.Matches(text);
```

Here i am trying to get exact "VO" (not from VOA or VO>>) from the text.Issue is along with correct match,i am also getting "VO" from "VO>>" which i don't want.Please help.

Comment: [`var res = text.Split().Where(p => String.Compare(p, matchterm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).ToList();`](https://ideone.com/XzU01c) will give you the necessary `VO`. But what do you need it for?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,but this won't help as above regex code is part of  workflow which uses match positions in further processes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the regex `(?<!\S)(VO)(?!\S)`:

```
string pattern = String.Format("(?<!\\S){0}(?!\\S)", matchterm);
```

It will ensure that `matchterm` is preceded by any whitespace character or the start of line and is followed by any whitespace character or the end of line

Comment: Please note \s will match for spaces but also for others whitespace characters : tab, page break, etc.

Comment: You can remove the class around \s they add nothing

Comment: Yes I also find the regex uselessly complex for what it does. It can easily be rewritten to something easier to read.

Comment: @AFract if you have a better one feel free to add an answer

Comment: Thanks for answer,i will try it

Comment: Use a better one without alternations: `@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)"` - you need no capturing group, BTW, since you can access the `Match` metadata easier. Also, if you are coding in VS2015, or just use C#6.0, you can use `var pattern = $@"(?<!\S){matchterm}(?!\S)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wans't aware of that feature, thanks :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew & Thomas Ayoub Thanks for your help. :)